# Double strikeout

Tags: formatting, strikeout

I'm using the `ulem` for strikethrough, but need two formats of strikethrough. I'm currently using `\dout{text}` which looks good, but the second`\xout{text}` makes the base text a little too unreadable.

I'm looking for a clean double-strikethrough... the closest I've gotten is:

`\newcommand\dout{\bgroup \markoverwith{\rule[0.2ex]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}\rule[0.8ex]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}}\ULon}`

but this creates a *slight* hatching effect. (It's good enough, but I figured I'd see if any of ye clever folk had a cleaner solution.)

[image: example]

Comment: Just a note that when I use the above `\dout` command, it doesn't work in captions, and it looks a bit faded compared to `\sout` (rule weight doesn't quite help).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is modified from the double underline macro of `ulem` (note that `\MakeRobust` is also defined by that package):

```
\def\dout{\bgroup
 \markoverwith{\lower-0.2ex\hbox
 {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern0.45ex\hrule}\kern-.03em}}%
 \ULon}
\MakeRobust\dout
```

and seems to work quite well:

[image: example]

Comment: Works a treat, thanks! A small problem in that it doesn't work in captions `! Undefined control sequence... \markoverwith ...ULC@box } \else \def \UL@leadtype ...` and then `! Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack = 5000]. \UL@on 1->\leavevmode ...` but not a problem for my case.

Comment: That (and a scaling problem) should be fixed now.

Comment: Hmmm... addition of `\UL@setULdepth` gives me an `Undefined control sequence.` for every use of `\dout` (inside or outside captions). `\MakeRobust` seems fine. Is `\UL` also in that package?

Comment: `\UL@setULdepth` is also from the package. Maybe you forgot the `\makeatletter`? Actually, that command was just a copy&paste error any you can remove it.

Comment: Better `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\def`, and avoid `\MakeRobust`. I suppose this answer got `\kern-.03em` after the other answer was entered.

Comment: This (and `\xout`) does not seem to work when you have limits, such as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

More an observation, then an answer, but too long for a comment: The effect dependens on the pdf viewer:

This is Evince (300%, 400%):
[image: evince 300] [image: evince 400]

It looks better in Acrobat (300%, 400%)
[image: acrobat 300] [image: acrobat 400]

At least until you zoom in really close (1600%):

[image: acrobat 1600]

How does it look when printed?

Comment: Good point. Was using SumatraPDF which looks similar to Evince above. It does look better on Acrobat. Printed, both look solid... though Acrobat a little more so (in fact a little too solid, making the text a little unreadable).

Answer (score 1):

I think Inserting `\hskip-0.1pt` in the first proposed code solves the problem of hatching.

```
    \newcommand\dout{
        \bgroup
        \markoverwith{%
            \rule[0.2ex]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}%
            \hskip-0.1pt
            \rule[0.8ex]{0.1pt}{0.4pt}%
        }
        \ULon
     }
     \MakeRobust\dout
```