# reledmac/reledpar does not work well with colors

Tags: color, reledmac, reledpar

I'm setting two texts beside each other in columns using reledmac/reledpar, the right column being a translation (that I'm correcting) of the left column. I'm using the `changes` package to annotate any corrections I make, and notice that colors "spill over" from the right column to the left, if the colored block spans more than one line. I assume this means that `\textcolor` pushes onto some color stack, which is preserved between the columns.

Is it possible to remedy this?

MWE, using both commands from from `changes` as well as manually using `\textcolor`/`\sout`; interestingly striking out text works flawlessly (albeit changing hyphenation), whereas it seems `\highlight` should not be used for more than a single word:

[image: MWE illustration]

```latex
% LATEX_CMD: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3706/9742
\def\dout{\bgroup
  \markoverwith{\lower-0.2ex\hbox
    {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern0.45ex\hrule}\kern-.03em}}%
  \ULon}
\MakeRobust\dout

\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name=Me, color=red]{ME}
\setcommentmarkup{\footnotesize[\emph{#1}]}
\setdeletedmarkup{\dout{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar
    \noindent
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit. Pellentesque tempus odio non neque finibus tincidunt. Proin
    venenatis massa non mattis accumsan. Donec ullamcorper auctor
    purus, in accumsan lorem bibendum feugiat. Nam condimentum neque
    orci, ut varius eros congue ac. Vestibulum quis mi lacinia,
    aliquam nunc non, consequat massa. Proin molestie vehicula arcu
    sed commodo. Fusce euismod feugiat volutpat. Praesent porttitor,
    urna quis suscipit rutrum, est lorem fringilla dui, id varius
    purus magna a erat. Sed at aliquam turpis. Nulla egestas, sapien
    non vehicula tincidunt, neque sem gravida ex, vitae faucibus magna
    risus sed libero. Vivamus sem neque, lacinia eu vestibulum
    aliquet, efficitur nec mauris.

    Curabitur ultricies non est in vulputate. Sed sollicitudin est
    tortor, vel luctus lectus posuere eget. Etiam ut scelerisque
    lectus, quis laoreet leo. Aenean laoreet sem id congue
    lacinia. Vivamus elit mi, luctus at aliquam ac, rhoncus sit amet
    diam. Maecenas fringilla elit eu pretium molestie. Vivamus eu
    mauris vitae libero rutrum fermentum sagittis eu quam. Donec
    vehicula scelerisque nisl sit amet porttitor.

    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar
    \noindent
    \sout{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Pellentesque tempus odio} non neque finibus
    tincidunt. Proin venenatis massa non mattis accumsan. Donec
    ullamcorper auctor purus, in accumsan lorem bibendum
    feugiat. \textcolor{red}{Nam condimentum neque orci, ut varius}
    eros congue ac. Vestibulum quis mi lacinia, aliquam nunc non,
    consequat massa. Proin molestie vehicula arcu sed commodo. Fusce
    euismod feugiat volutpat. Praesent porttitor, urna quis suscipit
    rutrum, \dout{est lorem fringilla dui, id varius purus magna a
      erat. Sed at} aliquam turpis. Nulla egestas, sapien non vehicula
    tincidunt, neque sem gravida ex, vitae faucibus magna risus sed
    libero. Vivamus sem neque, lacinia eu vestibulum aliquet,
    efficitur nec mauris.

    Curabitur ultricies non est in vulputate. Sed sollicitudin est
    tortor, vel luctus lectus posuere eget. Etiam
    \replaced[id=ME]{Hello there!}{ut scelerisque lectus, quis laoreet
      leo. Aenean laoreet sem id congue lacinia. Vivamus} elit mi,
    luctus at aliquam ac, rhoncus sit amet diam. Maecenas fringilla
    elit eu pretium molestie. \highlight[id=ME]{Vivamus eu mauris
      vitae libero rutrum fermentum sagittis eu quam. Donec} vehicula
    scelerisque nisl sit amet porttitor.

    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: If there is a general solution to `reledmac`'s issues with text color, I don't know of it. But a good workaround for the line numbers is to define their font color explicitly: `\renewcommand{\numlabfont}{\color{black}\normalfont\scriptsize}
`, this prevents the text color from spilling to the numbers.

Comment: As for the line-breaking issues. Actually, `\sout` has problems (independently of reledmac): it creates a box and can therefore cause an overfull line (see line 1R in your example!). Maybe switch to `\st`from the [soulutf8 package](https://ctan.org/pkg/soulutf8) (a revamping of [soul](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul) w/ better linebreaking). - `\highlight` also makes a box and an overfull line, as you noted. Normally, I'd recommend a redefinition via `\texthl{}` (customizable highlighting cmd from `soulutf8`). But with reledmac, this recreates your issues (the color spills over to the left column).

Comment: It is a knew bug of reledmac. An issue was opened many year ago. I tried to solve it, but was'nt able. I am sorry, I have yet no time for this.